# pyqtdeploy throws an extremely strange issue

Tags: android, python, qt, apk, pyqt5

I am using pyqtdeploy to pack a much simple python script into Qt Project. Then I will try to compile it as .apk file. I consider the environment has been completely set up so far, including Android SDK, Android NDK, Qt, android studio, ant etc. A strange error always appears when running pyqtdeploy.

Here is my code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLabel


class Main(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.build_inter()

    def build_inter(self):
        self.lb = QLabel("Test", self)
        self.lb.move(0, 0)

        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Main()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I intercepted a part of error information:

```
..\include/pyport.h:617:60: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token
 #                       define PyAPI_FUNC(RTYPE) __declspec(dllexport) RTYPE
                                                            ^
..\include/fileutils.h:109:1: note: in expansion of macro 'PyAPI_FUNC'
 PyAPI_FUNC(int) _Py_get_inheritable(int fd);
 ^
..\include/pyport.h:617:60: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token
 #                       define PyAPI_FUNC(RTYPE) __declspec(dllexport) RTYPE
                                                            ^
..\include/fileutils.h:111:1: note: in expansion of macro 'PyAPI_FUNC'
 PyAPI_FUNC(int) _Py_set_inheritable(int fd, int inheritable,
 ^
..\include/pyport.h:617:60: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token
 #                       define PyAPI_FUNC(RTYPE) __declspec(dllexport) RTYPE
                                                            ^
..\include/fileutils.h:114:1: note: in expansion of macro 'PyAPI_FUNC'
 PyAPI_FUNC(int) _Py_dup(int fd);
```

and the screenshot:

[image]

My config:

[image]

Have anyone encountered a similar problem? What am I supposed to do?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm far from being an expert, but in the documentation it reads it does not make sense to check "run application" unless the target environment is equal to the source environment. From your windows it seems you are cross compiling from Windows to Android, thus I would try to omit the last parameter of "Additional build steps" ("run application"). You would then have to test it yourself from e.g. Android studio I guess. Hope it helps.